# jquery toggle to hide or display div

Tags: jquery

I've written a code which checks if the div is set to `display:none;` or `display: block;`, but I think a better short code can also be made. Here is my code, can anyone help me out with a more flexible code?

```
$(".msgstreplylarge").toggle(
    function () {
        if($('.view_quick_reply').css('display') === 'none')
            $('.view_quick_reply').show();
        else
            $('.view_quick_reply').hide();
    },
    function () {
        if($('.stg_gall_cro_cnt').css('display') === 'block')
            $('.view_quick_reply').hide();
        else
            $('.view_quick_reply').show();
    }
);
```

Comment: you can use the jquery toogle() for that. that will automatic check this

Answer (score 2):

`$('#foo').toggle(showOrHide);` will do the same work . for further reference [check this link](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: OP should call it without the parameter, i.e., `$('.view_quick_reply').toggle()`, if the idea is to simply reverse the current visible/hidden state.